# TSQL - Query to verify continuity

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
  Id  |  PersonId  |    Date    |  Number  |  NumberOld  
------+------------+------------+----------+-----------
   1  |     1      |  2014 1 1  |    1     |      0      
   2  |     1      |  2014 1 2  |    2     |      1      
   3  |     1      |  2014 1 3  |    3     |      2      
   4  |     2      |  2014 1 1  |    1     |      0      
   5  |     2      |  2014 1 2  |    3     |      2      
   6  |     2      |  2014 1 3  |    4     |      3
```

What I want is a query, that gets me the person for which the continuity of the number and numberold is not given.

So for `PersonId = 1`, everything is alright, so the query shouldn't return person1.

```
1 - 0
2 - 1
3 - 2
```

But for `PersonId = 2` the continuity of the numbers is not given

```
1 - 0
3 - 2
4 - 3
```

Number 1 of the first record does not correspond to numberold 2 of the second record.

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: are the number of records per person variable or will there always be 3 or fewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LAG to look into the previous record. Thus you find mismatches and with the PersonIDs found you select the persons' histories:

```
select *
from mytable
where personid in
(
  select personid
  from
  (
    select personid, numberold, lag(number) over (partition by personid order by logdate, number) as numberbefore
    from mytable
  ) lookup
  where numberold <> numberbefore
)
order by personid, logdate, number;
```

Here is an SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/991e7/2.

Comment: hey cool idea i didn't know about LAG.. but when i try to execute it it says: The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled. do you know how i can enable theses features?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't. What version of SQL Server are you using? LAG was introduced in SQL Server 2012. See this link: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47116/in-microsoft-sql-server-2008-syntax-generates-the-error-the-parallel-data-ware and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this with a `left join` to find mismatches:

```
select t.person
from table t left join
     table tnext
     on t.person = tnext.person and t.number = tnext.numberold
where tnext.person is null
group by t.person
having count(*) > 1;
```

The `join` finds all rows where the numbers don't match.  However, there will always be at least one (the last one) for a given person.  This is filtered out using the `having` clause.

Answer (score 2):

I would be inclined to use `NOT EXISTS` vs `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` because as a general rule [it performs better in SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

```
SELECT  *
FROM    T AS t1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    T AS t2
            WHERE   t1.PersonID = t1.PersonID
            AND     t2.NumberOld = t1.Number
        );
```

It may not make any difference in your case, but the reason for potential the performance gain is SQL Server is not able to optimise the `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` method into an anti-semi join, that is to say it will return all results before filtering out the null values, whereas `NOT EXISTS` will stop searching as soon as a match is found. The article linked above goes into much more detail, but to demonstrate for your query, I created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE #T 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), 
    PersonId INT, 
    Date DATE,
    Number INT, 
    NumberOld INT
);
INSERT #T (PersonID, Date, Number, NumberOld) 
VALUES 
    (1, '2014-01-01', 1, 0), (1, '2014-01-02', 2, 1), (1, '2014-01-03', 3, 2),
    (2, '2014-01-01', 1, 0), (2, '2014-01-02', 3, 2), (2, '2014-01-03', 4, 3);
```

Then ran the two queries:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #T AS t1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    #T AS t2
            WHERE   t1.PersonID = t1.PersonID
            AND     t2.NumberOld = t1.Number
        );

SELECT  t1.*
FROM    #T AS t1
        LEFT JOIN #T AS t2
            ON  t1.PersonID = t1.PersonID
            AND t2.NumberOld = t1.Number
WHERE   t2.PersonID IS NULL;
```

Comparing the two plans you can see the anti-semi join in the top plan, but a normal join followed by a filter in the bottom plan:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The method below finds all the gaps for any number of people through a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (PersonId INT, Number INT, NumberOld INT)
INSERT @Data VALUES (1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 2),
    (2, 1, 0), (2, 3, 2), (2, 4, 3)

SELECT DISTINCT
    D1.PersonId
FROM @Data D1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Data D2
        ON D1.Number = D2.NumberOld
WHERE D2.PersonId IS NULL
```

**Yields output**

```
PersonId
-----------
2
```

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/645a6/1/0

the number of rows for a person should be equal to the difference of the maximum number and the minimum old number

fiddle isn't working... here's the sql

```
SELECT p.PersonID
FROM Person p
GROUP BY p.PersonID
HAVING COUNT(1) <> MAX(Number)-MIN(NumberOld)
```

Comment: hey unfortunately the fiddle is empty :(

Comment: strange. i put the sql in my answer.